# Change multiple values toString with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, laravel, indexing

So im getting 4 values as numbers with:

```
    <h3 class="u-text-size-h6"> </h3>
    <div class="js-numstepper tiempo">
    <input  class="tiempos" type="number" min="0" max="60">
    </div>
</div>
```

and:

`var tiempoInstruccion = document.getElementsByClassName('tiempos');`

Then i want to convert all the values to strings because i have a function that doesn't work with numbers only with text.

i tried this:

`var stringTiempo = tiempoInstruccion.toString();`
and also tried doigt it with a loop

the main problem that im having is with this function:

```
var tiempoInstruccion = document.getElementsByClassName('tiempos');
var seleccionTiempo = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tiempoInstruccion.length; i++) {
        var element = tiempoInstruccion[i].toString();

        var strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
        seleccionTiempo.push(strSel);
    }
```

i need to push those values to this array 
`var seleccionTiempo = []`

also tried changing the 
`element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;`
to 
`element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;`

im getting this message:
`TypeError: element.selectedIndex is undefined`

and im sure its because of the array is not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following function to extract your input values

```js
var tiempoInstruccion = [];
var seleccionTiempo = [];

function updatevalues(){
  var tiempoInstruccion = document.getElementsByClassName('tiempos');
  seleccionTiempo = [];
  for(var i=0;i<tiempoInstruccion.length;i++){
    var val = tiempoInstruccion[i].value;
    if(val.length>0){
      seleccionTiempo.push(val);
    }
  }
  console.log(seleccionTiempo);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="u-text-size-h6"> </h3>
   <div class="js-numstepper tiempo">
    <input  class="tiempos" type="number" min="0" max="60">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="u-text-size-h6"> </h3>
   <div class="js-numstepper tiempo">
    <input  class="tiempos" type="number" min="0" max="60">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="u-text-size-h6"> </h3>
   <div class="js-numstepper tiempo">
    <input  class="tiempos" type="number" min="0" max="60">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="u-text-size-h6"> </h3>
   <div class="js-numstepper tiempo">
    <input  class="tiempos" type="number" min="0" max="60">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updatevalues()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put some custom value in ur array. Then using javascript `map` function loop through all the item then push them into new array making them string

```js
var tiempoInstruccion = [56,67,57,52];
var seleccionTiempo = [];

tiempoInstruccion.map( item => {
  seleccionTiempo.push(item.toString());
})
console.log(seleccionTiempo)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

tiempos is a text box not a select box.you can access the options property in text box.Use this One It will work

var tiempoInstruccion = document.getElementsByClassName('tiempos')[0].value.toString();